# Linq mapping to multiple tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I working my way through the Apress "Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework" ( http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430210078 ) book, and in an example the author creates a link to a db table (as well as a fake repository) using linq like this:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace DomainModel.Entities
{
    [Table(Name = "Products")]
    public class Product
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        [Column] public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column] public string Description { get; set; }
        [Column] public decimal Price { get; set; }
        [Column] public string Category { get; set; }
        public string this[string propName]
        {
          get {
            if ((propName == "Name") && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                return "Please enter a product name";
            if ((propName == "Description") && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
                return "Please enter a description";
            if ((propName == "Price") && (Price < 0))
                return "Price must not be negative";
            if ((propName == "Category") && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Category))
                return "Please specify a category";
            return null;
        }
    }
    public string Error { get { return null; } } // Not required    }
}
```

creating an interface:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DomainModel.Entities;

namespace DomainModel.Abstract
{
    public interface IProductsRepository
    {
        IQueryable Products { get; }
        void SaveProduct(Product product);
        void DeleteProduct(Product product);
    }
}
```

a fake repository (not included) and then a real DB connection repository:-

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DomainModel.Abstract;
using System.Data.Linq;
using DomainModel.Entities;

namespace DomainModel.Concrete
{
    public class SqlProductsRepository : IProductsRepository
    {
        private Table productsTable;
        public SqlProductsRepository(string connectionString)
        {
            productsTable = (new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable();
        }

        public IQueryable Products
        {
            get { return productsTable; }
        }

        public void SaveProduct(Product product)
        {
            EnsureValid(product, "Name", "Description", "Category", "Price");

            // If it's a new product, just attach it to the DataContext
            if (product.ProductID == 0)
                productsTable.InsertOnSubmit(product);
            else {
                // If we're updating an existing product, tell the DataContext
                // to be responsible for saving this instance
                productsTable.Attach(product);
                // Also tell the DataContext to detect any changes since the last save
                productsTable.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, product);
            }

            productsTable.Context.SubmitChanges();
        }

        public void DeleteProduct(Product product)
        {
            productsTable.DeleteOnSubmit(product);
            productsTable.Context.SubmitChanges();
        }

        private void EnsureValid(IDataErrorInfo validatable, params string[] properties)
        {
            if (properties.Any(x => validatable[x] != null))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The object is invalid.");
        }
    }
```

off to a DB table "Products" with the column name specified and it works nicely.  I am using this technique in a real-world app, as it handles the DB access layer nicely, but I need to be able to access several tables from my object.  How can I do this - do I need to split my object up into a hierarchy that reflects its tables or can I access more than 1 table from the main object, with other additional objects hanging off it that have their own tables?  If so then how do I create the ORM links between the objects and tables?

Cheers

MH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the related tables to your repository interface, just as you have for Product and then create the concrete implementations in your repository class, again just as you have for Product.

I've used the same pattern on my app, I have two repositories, each handling 5-10 tables. There are two distinct groups of tables which are related, hence two repositories.

I would change the SQLRepository constructor thus:

```
    public SqlProductsRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        DataContext dc = new DataContext(connectionString);
        productsTable = dc.GetTable<Product>();
    }
```

You can then extend it easily thus e.g.:

```
    private Table<Order> ordersTable;

    public SqlProductsRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        DataContext dc = new DataContext(connectionString);
        productsTable = dc.GetTable<Product>();
        ordersTable = dc.GetTable<Order>();
    }

    IQueryable<Order> Orders
    {
        get { return from o in ordersTable select o; }
    }
```

EDIT - Answering comment

Here's an example of how to deliver subordinate objects (related tables) via this method:

```
[Table(Name="Projects")]
public class Project
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [Association(ThisKey="ID", OtherKey = "ProjectID")]
    private EntitySet<ProjectDate> _projectDates = new EntitySet<ProjectDate>();
    public IQueryable<ProjectDate> ProjectDates
    {
        get { return _projectDates.AsQueryable(); }
    }
}
```

And the ProjectDate class for completeness

```
[Table(Name="ProjectDates")]
public class ProjectDate
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public Guid ProjectID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public DateTime TargetDate { get; set; }
    [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
    public DateTime? ActualDate { get; set; }
    [Column(CanBeNull=true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    private EntityRef<Project> _project;
    [Association(ThisKey = "ProjectID", Storage = "_project", OtherKey = "ID")]
    public Project Project
    {
        get { return _project.Entity; }
        set { _project.Entity = value; ProjectID = _project.Entity.ID; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.
Sorry, I'm being stupid.  How would I create the relationship between the 2 tables within the main object (e.g. so you could access an orders collection for a product as, for example, Product.Orders

Comment: thanks a lot for that, I've got some UI code to write but then I'll get on and try that.

Comment: Thanks, started to get that working.  I had one problem that was driving me up the &$%^$^^%^$*% wall - I was getting a "Specified cast is not valid" error and what I thought was the AsQueryable -> IQueryable part, but after much muttering and poking I found it was due to a float in the db getting pulled into a float variable in the app - any idea why on earth that would throw an error?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be parity between the database data types and the C# data types. If I recall correctly I've had to use decimal for SQL floats but that may actually be overkill. It seems to throw the error at the AsQueryable call only because the LINQ isn't executed until then, most Linq errors not caught at design time will only emerge at the code line where you first try to access the data even though the actual error may be in the LINQ query itself.

Comment: Just thought, there must be a table about the different data types somewhere and lo and behold http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx. SQL Float is a C# double!

Comment: Thx for that.
Niiiiiiiiiiiiiiiice, oh dear lord, what _are_ they doing?????
Changed it into an int as that was more appropriate (the background context of the data is a little strange for this - don't worry why)

Comment: One more question (sorry to keep asking them).  If I have created these objects as IQueryable, do I have to create methods (I'm thinking on the project object, in your example) to add, update, and delete entries from that list, or can I set up write access to the subordinate objects directly?